# If $f(x)=ax+b$ is linear, why is $f(\gamma x) \neq \gamma f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The definition of a linear function is that it satisfies (among other things):
$$
f(\gamma x) = \gamma f(x)
$$

Then, why does for $f(x)=ax+b$, the following inequality appear:
$$
f(\gamma x) = a\gamma x+b \neq \gamma(a x+b) = \gamma f(x)
$$

Which means that:
$$
f(\gamma x) - \gamma f(x)
=
a\gamma x+b - \gamma(a x+b)
=
a\gamma x+b -  a\gamma x - \gamma b)
=
b(1-\gamma)
\neq
0
$$

What am I missing here?

**EDIT** TIL that there's a difference between a linear function and a linear map. Clarified in more detailed here for the curios: [intutive difference between linear map/transformation vs linear function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912970/intutive-difference-between-linear-map-transformation-vs-linear-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$f(x)=ax+b$$

is said to be "linear" because its graph is a straight line but (for $b\neq 0$) it is not linear in the sense of "linear map" (e.g. $f(x)=ax$).

Comment: So rotation and scaling is allowed for linear maps, but not translations?

Comment: @Void Yes, translations are not described by linear map (it is an affine map).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that, unless $b=0$, the map $x\mapsto ax+b$ is **not** a linear map.

Comment: So it's a linear function but not a linear map? Could you elaborate on the distinction please?

Comment: It's a linear function since its graph is a stright line, but that doesn't turn it into a linear map.

Comment: So a linear map is always a linear function but the other way around is not always a given?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I always called $ax+b$ an affine function (in France), I'm surprised it's called linear in some other countries, therefore the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the second half of the definition, namely $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Note that $f(x)=ax+b$ fails this condition in general, and is therefore not linear by this definition.