# Can a linear function have zero slope?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, slope

Can we say function $$y=f(x)=10$$ is a linear function? Can a linear function have zero slope?

Comment: Well it is a constant function. There is a definition of "linear function" which would only include $f(x)=cx$ but not with a nonzero constant.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912970

Comment: Thank both of you

Comment: This function is not linear. Please see my comment below the accepted answer. The only linear function with $0$ slope is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Seconding https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912970/intutive-difference-between-linear-map-transformation-vs-linear-function.  I think that question and answer explains it very clearly.

Comment: It is affine. Had to get my spake in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a linear function is a polynomial of degree one or less, including the zero polynomial. $f(x)=10$ has degree $0$, so it is linear.

Comment: Thank you. I understood it.

Comment: I have to point that this definition may vary in some languages. In french, a linear function is of the form $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=ax+b$ is not linear, but affine.

Comment: A linear function $f$ is one such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(ax)=af(x)$. $f(x)=10$ is not linear.

Comment: @SeanXie Most of us are mislead into believing that in our early education. For example, $f(x)=x$ is linear but $f(x)=x+1$ is not. This is because $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)\implies f(0)=0$ for a linear function $f$. So, for example, $y=mx$ is a linear function but $y=mx+b$ where $b\ne 0$ is not.

Comment: It is conventional in US middle-school education to call affine functions linear. I suspect that's the level of the OP, which makes this a perfectly fine answer, unworthy of deletion.

Comment: As Jacob notes, there are multiple definitions of "linear" in use, and many U.S. K-12 and college curricula (pre-linear algebra) would say that a polynomial function of degree at most 1 is a linear function. Having different uses of the same word in common circulation is not quite the same thing as people being "misled" into error.